# Disabling logging output from frameworks / Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've recently added a [Pod](http://cocoapods.org/) to my Xcode 9 iOS project whose console logging output is quite verbose, and makes it difficult for me to follow my own app's logging output in the debugging console.

Is there a build setting or other way to configure my project to suppress logging output from specific embedded frameworks / Pods?

I don't want to change the code of the framework itself, as that would get overridden the next time I update its Pod.

Comment: Can you tell which pod have you installed? maybe it has a settings inside to disable logs, or change their frequency

Comment: Sure, assuming the Pod has such a setting, I can turn it off. I was wondering if there is a general solution to the issue, though.